# How do I add links to Riak POJO objects?

Tags: java, scala, riak

Using the Riak Java client in Scala. When I go to store an object I use the following method, except it throws a `NullPointerException` when I go to `addLink`:

```
def store(clientId: String, userId: String, o: PointBalance) = {
    bucket.store(o).withRetrier(DB.retrier).execute()

    val tagThis = bucket.fetch(formatKey(clientId, userId)).r(2).withRetrier(DB.retrier).execute()
    tagThis.addLink(new RiakLink("users", userId, "owner"))
    bucket.store(tagThis).withRetrier(DB.retrier).execute()
  }
```

I was attempting to retrieve a basic `IRiakObject` without POJO deserialization so it would expose the `addLink` method, but it *appears* that Riak will not return an object unless it is of that POJO class.

How can I add a `RiakLink` to a basic POJO? Thanks.

### Update

For some reason the fetch above is retrieving null objects. Not sure why this is. The only difference between my normal `fetch` method and the method here is that I am deserializing to a POJO. See here:

Normal: `bucket.fetch(formatKey(clientId, userId), classOf[PointBalance]).r(2).withConverter(converter).withRetrier(DB.retrier).execute()`

Fetch IRiakObject: `bucket.fetch(formatKey(clientId, userId)).r(2).withRetrier(DB.retrier).execute()`

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am looking for a way to do something similar (add indexes).

Comment: Actually if you're just doing indexes, on a Scala `case class` you can annotate the field with `@(RiakIndex@field)(name = "fieldname")`. You'll need to modify the Riak config directly to enable indexing.

Comment: I didn't realize this was scala. In my case it's in Java and the object is a HashMap. I guess it's slightly different, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Java annotation would be similar. Would look something like `@RiakIndex("fieldname")` I think.

Comment: I found an example of what are you referring to here: https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/com/megacorp/commerce/Customer.java  However, in my case I am not using a POJO, but rather a HashMap since I have arbitrary field names.

Comment: Ah are you trying to index every field in the map? not sure if it's possible since Riak has to be directly told what index to build. but how about `URL.Encode` a separate field of all of the HashMap values? can you open a new S.O. question?